# State machine Modelling Query regarding transitions originating from any state

Tags: java, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I have query regarding state machine modeling.My state machine looks like this:
States: a,b,c,d,e
Transitions/events: E1,E2,E3,E4,E5
a--E1-->b---E2-->c--E5--> e

Some transitions E3 and E4 can occur from any state(i.e. both b & c) and terminate the state machine i.e. moves the state machine to terminal state

How to model transitions E3 & E4 in this scenario?
I am using Spring state machine for implementation.How to model these transitions using spring state machine?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking hierarchical states are used to prevent state explosion where you create more and more similar type of transitions from multiple states into some other state.

There are no `wildcard` transitions but if you create parent state `p` and create `b` and `c` as its child states, you can draw transition from state `p`.

Comment: Thanks Janne. So you are implying that -> create sub-machine with state b & c . then draw the transitions E3,E4 from parent machine to sub machine.?

Comment: Sorry I modified my answer as I didn't meant to use event id's as states which probably confused you. I didn't meant to draw transitions from parent to childs, but just having a shared transition in parent. Then if parent exists, it's childs are also exited.